# CSS (Override bootstrap core)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote the following **CSS**:

**MyForm.css**

```
.my-container [class^="col-md"] {
   .my-inner {
   padding : 10 px;
   background-color: #eee;
   .... etc...
}
```

If i use it in my code:

```
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="divTabPortfolios">
     <div class="my-inner">

     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="divTab">
     <div class="my-inner">

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. If I delete the subclass .my-inner it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really possibe to use the subclass that way?
I would have done something like:

```
.my-container [class^="col-md"] .my-inner {
      padding : 10 px;
      background-color: #eee;
      .... etc...
}
```

...depending of what you try to acheve.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the markup, it looks like you're trying to use a preprocessor like LESS or SASS. The reason the CSS isn't outputting correctly is because you didn't close `.my-inner`.

If you're using a preprocessor, it should look like this:

```
.my-container [class^="col-md"] {
   .my-inner {
     padding : 10 px;
     background-color: #eee;
     .... etc...
   } <-- forgot this closing tag
}
```

If you're using plain CSS, see Fredric's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your html code to this

### HTML

```
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="divTabPortfolios">
     <div class="my-inner">

     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="divTab">
     <div class="my-inner">

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You missed the double quotes , maybe this is causing problem in your html code and also check this for css code.

### CSS

```
.my-container [class^="col-md"]

.my-inner
{
      padding : 10 px;
      background-color: #eee;
      .... etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are removing subclass .my-inner from MyForm.css or the HTML page?
2. As Dead has said, you stylesheet must be after bootstrap's, so I
   ask, is that in the correct order?
3. If you inspect your page in
   the browser, can you see your custom properties there?
4. Try to write you .my-inner class directly (removing `.my-container [class^="col-md"]`).

If none of that work, try to post more details about.